# Add List of string if it can't be found

Tags: c#

I have

```
List<List<string>> source
```

which contains for example

```
{{"a","b"},{"c","d"}}
```

I also have a

```
List<List<string>> target
```

which contains for example

```
{{"a","b"},{"e","f"}}
```

What is the easiest way I could get the `List<string>` in `source` that cannot be found in `target`, be included in the `target`?

Here `{"c","d"}` can be found in `source` but not `target`, therefore after assignment the `target` should be

```
{{"a","b"},{"e","f"},{"c","d"}}
```

Comment: Would `{"d", "c"}` be added to both? (i.e. does sublist order matter)?

Comment: It would not, the order matter.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Linq.Union` with custom comparer:

```
target = target.Union(source, new MyListComparer())  // Use the custom comparer to avoid duplication of the equal sequences.
               .ToList();
```

With the equality comparer (if you want to have order independant comparison use the second choice in the `Equals` function):

```
public class MyListComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<string> x, List<string> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);  // Use this if { "a", "b" } != { "a", "b" }
        //return x.Count == y.Count && x.Count == x.Intersect(y).Count();  // Use this if { "a", "b" } == { "a", "b" }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<string> obj)
    {
        // GetHashCode is used to make the comparison faster by not comparing two elements that does not have the same hash code.
        // GetHashCode must satisfy the following condition
        //  (x == y) implies (GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y))
        // If your are extremely lazy, you can always return 0 but then the complexity of Union will be quadratic instead of linear.
        return obj.Sum(item => item.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work, however the `GetHashCode()` function would see {"a", "b"} and {"b", "a"} as equal lists.

Comment: @RoyDictus GetHashCode() can always return 0. The Union will still be correct. Because GetHashCode() does not require "_(GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y)_ implies _x == y_".

Comment: The union will still be correct, that is true, but the point of GetHashCode() is that it can identify objects uniquely, and therefore GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y) should really mean that x == y. That is the whole point of hash functions. And as MSDN states, "A hash code is a numeric value that is used to *identify an object during equality testing*. It can also serve as an index for an object in a collection.".

Comment: @RoyDictus It is NOT possible to have this property for objects that can have more than 2^32 different values. It is mathematically impossible. Because in this case GetHashCode is surjective!

Comment: I think in this scenario it makes more sense to simply return 0. The hash code is meant as a short cut, so that the potentially expensive `Equals` doesn't have to be called if the hash codes are not the same. However, in the current implementation, GetHashCode is just as expensive as `Equals`, defeating the purpose.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That's not totally right. With this GetHashCode, doing Union between 2 lists of _N_ elements (containing M elements) will call _2N_ times _MyListComparer.GetHashCode_, ie _2NM_ times _string.GetHashCode_. Then, if we are lucky 0 times _MyListComparer.Equals_. If _GetHashCode_ always returns 0, _MyListComparer.Equals_ will be called _N^2_ times and _string.Equals_ _AN^2_ times with _1 <= A <= M_. So the best solution depends on _N_ and _M_. Testing is the best way to be sure.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth A much better approach to returning 0 (if you do that you may as well just use a List, not a HashSet) is to base the hash code off of the first X item (I like using 5) rather than all items.  It's enough to differentiate most items for most data sets, but because it only takes a fixed number of items it's O(1).  Just add a `Take(5)` before the `Sum`.  Also, if you multiply each item with the aggregate instead of add, and add a value to each item before doing so, you can ensure it's not order insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ:

```
target = source.Union(target).Distinct(new YourComparer()).ToList();
```

Then you would need to create a new class that inherits from IEqualityComparer (see [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/IEqualityComparer.aspx) for an example of doing that) that would do the exact comparisons that you want.

Comment: Are you sure lists will be compared by items?

Comment: `Contains()` uses reference equality, not equality of content... So this would not work if there are two separate but identical lists, one in `source` and the other in `target`.

Comment: If you aren't expecting `Union` to ensure distinction you should just use `Concat`, to semantically represent what you mean.  Or, better yet, just pass the custom comparer to `Union` in the first place.